# shell_exec empty response for nslookup query

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, networking, shell-exec

I am using Ubuntu and xampp, I am trying to execute the command `nslookup gmail.com` via. PHP, but I am getting an empty response. The same thing worked while I tried on a windows machine as well as in a Linux server running CentOS.

FYI `nslookup gmail` gives proper response when I run the command directly on my terminal, the problem is only when I try to do it via. php.

I even tried doing a `which nslookup` and then 
`$nslookup = shell_exec("/usr/bin/nslookup $server");` with no help, but the same blank response.

Although **Note** that the command `whoami` when executed from PHP(which I have commented in the following code) does give a proper response of `daemon`

I am very new to Ubuntu, so a little help would be great.

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
$server = explode("@", $email)[1];
echo $server;

$nslookup = shell_exec("nslookup $server");
// $nslookup = shell_exec("whoami");
print_r($nslookup);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The php script executes as less privileged www user (daemon in your case) when you execute via web browser. It doesn't have enough privilege to execute command `nslookup`. I won't recommend increasing privilege of www user, which is a security risk. As an alternative try [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) php function. It returns IPv4 address corresponding to a given Internet host name.

```
<?php
 $email = $_GET['email'];
 $server = explode("@", $email)[1];
 echo $server;
 $ip = gethostbyname($server);
 echo $ip;
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to increase the privilege of www user?

Comment: Why don't you use gethostbyname? They both do the same.